# What is the proper way to minify many jquery plugins into one file?

Tags: jquery, minify

I have several plugins I am using for my site, like 8 of them and instead of loading 8 separate minified plugins. I would like to load only one big minified file.

So I downloaded all plugins in an uncompressed state.  Then I pasted each plugin into one file one after another.  After that I minified that one file.  However, this seems to not work.  For example a carousel that used to work before I tried this now just errors out.

So my question is how do I go about doing this?  Could it be because of namespacing issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What tool was used to minify it?  What is the error?

Comment: maybe some scripts are using the same variables, are you using php or asp.net?

Comment: You could try minifying each file first then merge all the minified files into one.

Comment: I don't really know what errors as it is different for different plugins and some do work...I used any online js compressor like YUI.  I am using PHP and I have already tried minifying all of them first and combining but it is worse as there will be duplicate variables if you do this.

Comment: Another library you could try https://github.com/vincpa/RxLoader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to combine all files AFTER all js have been minified.

If they do not conflict with each other when using the unminified version, then it is not a problem of namespacing.

The only thing you should bear in mind is to add a `;` at the end and at the beginning of each file.

Also, if you use Asp .Net MVC 4 there are many tools available for doing this automatically. It is called Bundling and Transforming. This is one of them: http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Actually I tried this before and it was even worse...The reason is if you minified them separately, there will be a bunch of duplicate variables...during minification, it changes your variable names to like a, b, c, d...etc. This shortens the code...so for each plugin that is minified will have those variables if it isn't already assigned.  Thus minifying all together will eliminate this issue..This is just from my experience, hence I didn't go this way.

Comment: but that should never happen! each plugin should be encapsulated in their own container. According to jQuery the best practice is to start the plugin with `(function($,window){ ` (check the getting started section here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: Well the code I get is straight from source.  It has not been altered by myself.  It could be possible that some plugins didn't do this but I am not certain...

Answer (score 0):

There's a PHP library for that which I used. It did a pretty good job.

[Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/)